# iOS Facebook auth dialog doesn't show allow & not allow button

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

I do as the [Facebook Developers website](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/), below are my codes,

```
fbPermissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                @"email", @"user_birthday", @"user_hometown", @"user_location", 
                @"user_work_history",@"friends_hometown", @"friends_location",
                @"friends_work_history", @"publish_stream", nil];
[delegate.facebook authorize:fbPermissions delegate:self];
```

I thought it works like this:

1. If you aren't login, it shows login dialog then redirect to auth dialog (which contains Allow/Don't Allow buttons below), to need some permissions. The auth dialog may like [this](http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/ios_perms_app.png).
2. If you are login, it skips login dialog and shows auth dialog.

but my problem is It doesn't show the auth dialog to need some permissions. Why? please help me if you knows. thank you.

PS. My English is poor so I doubt if you are clear about my question.

Comment: Have you ever seen the permissions dialog with your application?  In many cases this will only appear the first time.  Are you testing on a device with the Facebook iOS application installed or are you authenticating through Safari?

Comment: You are right! In iPhone simulator it never shows permissions dialog, but in device, it shows. Thank you.